# Meteor get event in iron:router controller

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Im working on a website in meteor. I just started working with controllers but cant figure out how to get a button click for instance.

I have the following temnplate:

```
<template name="login">
    <form>
        <input type="email" name="loginEmail">
        <input type="password" name="loginPassword">
        <input type="submit" class="login" value="Login">
    </form>
</template>
```

And my controller:

```
LoginController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'login',

  'click .login': function(e, t) {
      alert('submit button is clicked');
    }
  });
```

Now when I click the submit button the page reloads and passes all data to the url. this is not at all what I want. I want the alert to pop up.

I dont quite know where to start and I think it has something to do with the fact that I dont understand the way I should use controllers. Before using controllers this worked:

```
Template.login.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var emailVar = event.target.loginEmail.value;
        var passwordVar = event.target.loginPassword.value;
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar);
        console.log('loggin in');
    }
});
```

So how could I achieve the same thing inside my controller? Or should I make a method for it?

NOTE: I use iron:router to call the controller:

```
Router.route('/login', {
  name: 'login',
  controller: 'LoginController'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that an `input` of 'submit' type will submit the form, which will trigger a page reload as the default target for a form is the same URL.
So you have to prevent the default behavior of your button to avoid form submission, like this:

```
'click .login': function(e, t) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('submit button is clicked');
}
```

Also, you cannot get template events in a `RouteController` you will have to stick with `Template.login.events` as you were actually doing at the being. However, you can change the event from `submit form` to `click .login` like this:

```
Template.login.events({
  'submit form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var emailVar = event.target.loginEmail.value;
    var passwordVar = event.target.loginPassword.value;
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar);
    console.log('loggin in');
  }
  //OR
  'click .login': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //your logic here
  }
});
```

Comment: Nope, still reloading. are you sure it is the right place to do this inside the controller?

Comment: no right, didn't realize that, you won't be able to get template events I think in the route controller, you will still have to use the template events function `Template.login.events`. And probably still `event.preventDefault();` I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still have a problem tho. if I want to use Template.login.event I need to import both the login template and the Template package. But I think I dont want to do this inside the RouterController since I dont want to import the template file inside the controller. So should I make a seperate client file for handling events etc?

Comment: yes usually you have a separate js file containing the template 'logic', like helpers, events, etc. You don't have to 'import' this file in the Router as it's the template name that will help Meteor to find the corresponding Template logic. Just create a client file containing `Template.login....` and Meteor will bind the logic to the html template

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only have to add a "preventDefault" before the alert to make it work.

So you should modify your code as the following:

```
LoginController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'login',

  'click .login': function(e, t) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('submit button is clicked');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Nope, still reloading. are you sure it is the right place to do this inside the controller?